# Which site would this question about program design be best for?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Here is my question:

> The problem is this, I have a program like this:
>
> util->core->Gui
>
> I'm trying to update the Gui from the core process. The thing is though, the only way to do that would be to do something like this:
>
> util->Gui->Core
>
> because Core would have to know about Gui. Is there a better solution? E.g. how can Core update Gui without Core knowing about Gui?

Where would the best place to ask it be?

Comment: You'll have to come up with a good title anyway, so: please add that to the title of this very question too!

Comment: Sounds like whiteboard question. [programmers.se] maybe?

Comment: looks like someone asked the question already: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/138843/

Comment: @vis.15 then it is/was the right place.

Comment: I posted this question instead: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/219411/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is, according to its [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)<sup>1</sup>:

> a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development. If you have a question about...
>
> - algorithm and data structure concepts
> - **design patterns**
> - developer testing
> - development methodologies
> - freelancing and business concerns
> - quality assurance
> - software architecture
> - software engineering
> - software licensing

It sounds to me like your question falls under the **design patterns** point - maybe try asking there?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Fine, on-topic page. FAQ sounds better.</sup>